# How do I get fractional seconds in func.now() with SQLAlchemy ORM and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, orm, python-datetime

In short: when I add entries to a table in sqlite with the primary key being a default timestamp, I get a "UNIQUE constraint failed" error because the timestamps have no fractional seconds. How do I get SQLalchemy to use fractional seconds in func.now()l

In long:
Given the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import func, Column, DateTime, Time
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Connection, Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    """Base class for the database."""


class Table1(Base, MappedAsDataclass):
    """Table."""

    __tablename__ = "dummy table"

    timestamp: Mapped[dt.datetime] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, 
                                                   autoincrement=False, 
                                                   server_default=func.now())
    data: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable = True)


if  __name__ == "__main__":
    engine: Engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    record1 = Table1(data=1)
    record2 = Table1(data=2)
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add(record1)
        session.commit()
        # time.sleep(2)
        session.add(record2)
        session.commit()
```

And based on the [SQLAlchemy SQLite Datetime doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.DATETIME):

The default string storage format is:

```
"%(year)04d-%(month)02d-%(day)02d %(hour)02d:%(minute)02d:%(second)02d.%(microsecond)06d"
```

e.g.:

```
2021-03-15 12:05:57.105542
```

I would think I would get fractional seconds. Instead, the output from the code above with the `time.sleep(2)` not commented out is:

```
2023-06-14 12:32:17 1
2023-06-14 12:32:19 2
```

with no fractional seconds.

On that same page above, I see there is a way to customize the format, but I don't quite see how to get the new DATETIME object into the sqlite dialect.

So: how do I get func.now() to return a time with fractional seconds for a server side default timestamp?

Comment: How does this behave with `utcnow()`? Using `now()` is less than optimal because timezone changes and daylight savings time will create duplicates.

Comment: With sqlalchemy_utc and utcnow(), there are now microseconds! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using package sqlalchemy_utc and function utcnow() solves the problem.